# Strange symbols in console when using ILogger in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, logging, console, ilogger

In a Xamarin application, I'm using `ILogger` from the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package, like this:

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        // Dependency injection
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
```

and somewhere else (`Logger` is provided via dependency injection), simply

```
Logger.LogDebug("OK");
```

When I run my code, I see all kinds of strange symbols like `\^[[40m` in my Visual Studio for Mac console (highlighted):

```
2022-05-16 14:41:32.338270+0200 Example.iOS[33578:809127] \^[[40m\^[[37mdbug\^[[39m\^[[22m\^[[49m: Example.Communication.AuthenticationClient[0]
      OK
```

What are they, and how do I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These symbols are used to [color up your console](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/), but Visual Studio doesn't support them (at least on macOS).

It's easy to disable them via the [DisableColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.consoleloggeroptions.disablecolors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) property of the console logger options, like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole(options => options.DisableColors = true));
```

(in later .NET versions, this property has been superseded by [ColorBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.console.simpleconsoleformatteroptions.colorbehavior?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-logging-console-simpleconsoleformatteroptions-colorbehavior))